# How to GC (remove) threads of GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, winapi, garbage-collection, mingw

I noticed that when I use the function `GetOpenFileName` a lot of threads get allocated in my application. How do I go about removing these after the dialog is closed and the function returns? I have also experienced `SIGSEGV` errors in these threads that do not crash my application but are still annoying as they come out of nowhere and might cause serious memory problems later and also win32 api shouldn't be flawed like this, should it? Am I doing something wrong?

Also I'm a beginner in c/c++ so don't go too hard on me please.

My code:

```
OPENFILENAME open;
ZeroMemory(&open, sizeof(open));
char szFileName[2048] = {};

open.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
open.hwndOwner = NULL;
open.lpstrFilter = "Képek\0*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp\0\0";
open.lpstrFile = szFileName;
open.nFileOffset = 1;
open.nMaxFile = 2048;
open.lpstrTitle = "Képek kiválasztása..";
open.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

std::string links = "";
if (GetOpenFileName(&open)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: There are no `SIGSEGV` error signals in Windows. You must be running a different OS. On Windows, segmentation faults are reported as SEH exceptions (`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about those threads.  The dialog does create some worker threads that are managed by the OS itself, and there could also be third-party Explorer plugins installed that also get loaded indirectly by the dialog's use of Explorer and which create their own threads.  As long as the dialog is not crashing your code, just ignore the extra threads.  They are OS-layer threads that don't concern your app.

Comment: Also what about allocated memory? Is there no way of getting rid of that stuff? Any reason for the OS to keep these threads and memory associated with them? Do they get reused and if I only call this function once in my program, there is no reason for any cache of it, can none of this be controlled?

Comment: Again, this is all happening *outside of your app*, so ignore it.  The memory is not allocated in your app, it is in the OS itself.  The threads are managed by the OS, not your app.  No, none of this behavior can be controlled from inside your app.  It is transparent to your app, used internally by the dialog and the OS as private implementation details.  So just ignore it and move on.

Comment: Guess I can live with that. But still a bit hard to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: The OS may be running threads to monitor items for changes, or allocating and caching memory for later re-use, etc. The OS is doing something internally to make sure the dialog does what it needs to do.  You don't need to worry about the details.  You asked for an "Open File" dialog, so you get an "Open File" dialog, whatever it takes.